# Autogenerate wrapper classes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, wrapper

I do a lot of work with a library in which almost all classes are uninheritable, yet I want to extend them.

Say class A is uninheritable. I frequently create "wrapper" classes by storing a `self._obj` as an atrribute, then manually implementing all the methods and all the attributes (with `@property`) to perform some behavior before calling the same method on `_obj`. [Here's an example](https://github.com/controversial/ui2/blob/012e8242e4522f3e9c9b953187bfc81f77eb726d/ui2/view_classes/TableView.py#L7-L53).

Is there a better way to extend uninheritable classes, or at least some way to automate this tedious process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: just define `__getattr__` to lookup the attribute on `self._cell`.

Comment: How does this work if I want to add to existing methods? Do I implement those the old way? Also, will I need `__setattr__` for those attributes that can be written?

Comment: Can you give an example of "adding to existing methods"?

Comment: Some of the attributes I'm wrapping I'm using `@property.setter` on. See the linked file on GitHub.

Comment: @LukeTaylor what Daniel proposes is to add the following methods to your wrapper: `def __getattr__(self, name): return getattr(self._cell, name)` and `def __setattr__(self, name, value): return setattr(self._cell, name, value)`

Comment: @Frodon I know. Thanks for clarifying anyway, though.